# Something wrong with CACM-RH template .cls file? Bad section spacing

Tags: spacing, document-classes, acm

I need to use the CACM-RH template (https://cacm.acm.org/about-communications/author-center/author-guidelines/research-highlights-template/).

However, upon compilation I find that the section/subsection headers (other than the abstract) don't seem to have the right spacing after their title. Is there something I need to change in the .cls file, which was last updated in 2008?

[image: screenshot of PDF output showing section text overlapping the headers]

MWE `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{research4cacm}
\begin{document}

\title{Testing...
\thanks{The original version of this paper is entitled ``XXX" and was
published in (Title of publication, publication date, publisher.)}
}

\numberofauthors{7}
\author{
\alignauthor
Fake Name\\
       \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
       \email{email}
\alignauthor
Fake Name\\
       \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
       \email{email}
\alignauthor
Fake Name\\
       \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
       \email{email}
\and
\alignauthor
Fake Name\\
       \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
       \email{email}
\alignauthor
Fake Name\\
       \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
       \email{email}
\alignauthor
Fake Name\\
       \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
       \email{email}
\and
\alignauthor
Fake Name\\
       \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
       \email{email}
}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\section{Related Work}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\section{Methods}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\section{Findings}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\section{Conclusions}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\section{Acknowledgments}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\balancecolumns
\end{document}
```

The `research4cacm.cls` class file is long (~55 KB), so I didn't include it here. It can be downloaded from the official link above, and here is a pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/tXqgMAyJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given template used to typeset “correctly” up to TeX Live 2020. But that's essentially by pure chance as the consequence of a large number of hacks.

This is part of the issue

```
\newfont{\secfnt}{ptmb8t at 12pt}
\newfont{\secit}{ptmbi8t at 12pt}    %13 Jan 00 gkmt
\newfont{\subsecfnt}{ptmri8t at 11pt}
\newfont{\subsecit}{ptmbi8t at 11pt}  %
\newfont{\ttlfnt}{phvb8t at 18pt}
\newfont{\ttlit}{phvbo8t at 18pt}    % GM 2/4/2000
\newfont{\subttlfnt}{phvr8t at 14pt}
\newfont{\subttlit}{phvro8t at 14pt} % GM 2/4/2000
\newfont{\subttlbf}{phvb8t at 14pt}  % 13 Jan 00 gkmt
\newfont{\aufnt}{phvr8t at 12pt}
\newfont{\auit}{phvro8t at 12pt}     % GM 2/4/2000
\newfont{\affaddr}{phvr8t at 10pt}
\newfont{\affaddrit}{phvro8t at 10pt} % GM 2/4/2000
\newfont{\eaddfnt}{phvr8t at 12pt}
\newfont{\ixpt}{ptmr8t at 9pt}
\newfont{\confname}{ptmri8t at 8pt}
\newfont{\crnotice}{ptmr8t at 8pt}
\newfont{\ninept}{ptmr8t at 9pt}
```

Such code has been deprecated for about 30 years. ***No*** document or document class should have `\newfont`, unless the user or class writer know ***very precisely*** what they're doing. And this is definitely not the case, for several reasons:

1. it's simply absurd to use Times for section titles and Computer Modern for the text;
2. more importantly, commands declared with `\newfont` will not provide suitable baselineskip.

Regarding point 2, the class maintainers tried to fix by declaring `\baselineskip 14pt` in the code for `\section`, but this is a bad hack and doesn't really solve the issue

```
\def\section{%
    \@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}{-10\p@ \@plus -4\p@ \@minus -2\p@}% GM
    {4\p@}{\baselineskip 14pt\secfnt\@ucheadtrue}%
}

\def\subsection{%
    \@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}{-8\p@ \@plus -2\p@ \@minus -\p@}
    {4\p@}{\secfnt}%
}
\def\subsubsection{%
    \@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}{-8\p@ \@plus -2\p@ \@minus -\p@}%
    {4\p@}{\subsecfnt}%
}
```

The following is a try to get something better.

```
\documentclass{research4cacm}

%%% Note to copy editors: the following fixes are needed
%%% in order to get decent output in the temporary version
%%% for the submission
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\secfnt}{\fontfamily{ptm}\fontsize{12}{14}\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\subsecfnt}{\fontfamily{ptm}\fontsize{11}{13}\itshape}
\def\section{%
    \@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}{-10\p@ \@plus -4\p@ \@minus -2\p@}% GM
    {14\p@}{\secfnt\@ucheadtrue}%
}

\def\subsection{%
    \@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}{-8\p@ \@plus -2\p@ \@minus -\p@}
    {14\p@}{\secfnt}%
}
\def\subsubsection{%
    \@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}{-8\p@ \@plus -2\p@ \@minus -\p@}%
    {14\p@}{\subsecfnt}%
}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\abstract\expandafter{\abstract\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
\makeatother
%%% end of fixes

\begin{document}

\title{Testing...
\thanks{The original version of this paper is entitled ``XXX" and was
published in (Title of publication, publication date, publisher.)}
}

\numberofauthors{7}
\author{
\alignauthor
Fake Name\\
       \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
       \email{email}
\alignauthor
Fake Name\\
       \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
       \email{email}
\alignauthor
Fake Name\\
       \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
       \email{email}
\and
\alignauthor
Fake Name\\
       \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
       \email{email}
\alignauthor
Fake Name\\
       \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
       \email{email}
\alignauthor
Fake Name\\
       \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
       \email{email}
\and
\alignauthor
Fake Name\\
       \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
       \email{email}
}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\section{Related Work}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\section{Methods}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\subsection{A very long title that will wrap into two lines if we add more text}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\subsubsection{A very long title that will wrap into two lines if we add more text}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\subsection{Findings}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\section{Conclusions}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\section{Acknowledgments}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\balancecolumns
\end{document}
```

[image]

But the people at the conference seem to ignore that the ACM has a specific class, called `acmart` that does justice of the plethora of special (and usually badly written) classes for ACM conferences.

Anyway, the journal site says

> Authors are advised that submitting a paper in the template does not reflect a camera-ready version of the paper. Like all editorial material approved for publication in the montly Communications magazine, these papers will be edited and copyedited. Authors will receive page proofs to review for any last-minute changes or corrections.

so you shouldn't worry too much about the final output. Clearly mark the proposed fix so the copy editors will know about it.